# Transferring Excel2010 .xlsb files to new PC using Office365

Tags: microsoft-excel-2010, office365, windows-11

Are there likely to be significant problems transferring large Excel2010 .xlsb files (~10MB) from a WIN7 PC running Office2010 to a new WIN11 machine running Office365 Personal? There are no user-written macros in the files.

I've checked earlier posts here and can see that macros /.xlsm files can have problems, but aside from the usual minor 2010...2013..2016..2019.. format/version compatibility changes, am I likely to run into any major problems relating to .xlsb files?

[Incidentally: Advice from a Microsoft sales person after checking internally was "but for the Binary XLSB files, it must be saved in XLSX or XLSM file format before being unprotected. If you already have the 365 Personal you can still open edit and save XLSB files with it, but you have to install the free Microsoft Office Compatibility Pack first."

First, there is no Microsoft Office Compatibility Pack for modern versions, and second, I don't know what he meant about "before being unprotected".]

Your advice as to "significant problems transferring large Excel2010 .xlsb files (~10MB) from a WIN7 PC running Office2010 to a new WIN11 machine running Office365 Personal" will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Transferring Excel2010 .xlsb files to new PC using Office365

As you have laid it out, no issue.

Set up your new machine with Windows 10 / 11, install Office 365.  I am using Windows 11 / Office 365.

Office 365 will read your files just fine, including Outlook PST files to set up new Outlook.

I have numerous old Office files open / read them without issue.

Size of files will not be any problem with large files.

Key is to install new machine, copy the files over, then use them.

Comment: Excellent - thank you so much, John; and also as regards Outlook, which was my other main concern.

Comment: You should be just fine.  Me:  Windows 7, Office 2010 to Windows 8, Office 2013, to Windows 10, Office 365, to Windows 11 Office 365 and I have absolutely everything.